# repeat Pandas group by index levels on all rows?

Tags: pandas

I don't do group by over multiple index columns very often.

It seems like the default behaviour is to only display an index level each time it changes, like `second`  in [this example](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#grouping-dataframe-with-index-levels-and-columns)

How can I get output in which the value for column `second` is repeated on each row?

```
In [54]: df.groupby([pd.Grouper(level=1), "A"]).sum()
Out[54]: 
          B
second A   
one    1  2
       2  4
       3  6
two    1  4
       2  5
       3  7
```

Comment: You could do `.reset_index()` if you don't need them to be in your index which would do what you are asking I beleive.

Comment: Well, I do want all index levels s to appear on all rows. `is_counts.reset_index(inplace=True)`  was helpful. Thanks.